# Solving Vout for a differentiating op-amp with added resistor?

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, current, resistance, capacitance

I searched through old posts and didn't find a direct answer to this - there were practical explanations but no circuit math.

I am to solve the \$V_{out}\$ value for a differentiating *op-amp*. I know that normally this equation is 
    $$V_{out} = -R  C  \frac{dv_{in}}{dt}$$

However, the circuit I'm solving is as follows: [image]

Would the equation for \$V_{out}\$ now just be $$V_{out} = -R_2 C\frac{dV_{in}}{dt}$$ ?

I feel like something is missing in my understanding of how to include R1.

You guys have answered a few times giving Laplace methods of solving - I understand the math behind that but it is beyond the scope of the course I am in. We have only been taught to solve using Kirchoff's laws, so if you could show me that method, it would be appreciated?

Thanks,
inkblots

Comment: I suppose, you know why it is necessary to use R1 - although it will disturb the differencing action heavily?

Comment: My understanding is that it is to reduce noise?

Comment: No - without R1 the circuit would not work because it would be unstable. The stability criterion is violated (best case: phase margin some degrees only).

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the current circuit using Laplace transformations. Assuming node 3 is at virtual ground.
$$ \frac{V_s}{R_1 + \frac{1}{sc}} = -\frac{V_o}{R_2}$$

$$V_o = \frac{R_2V_ssC}{R_1sC+1}------(1)$$

Now you can solve this one easily by using inverse laplace tranformation and reach at this solution,

$$ V_o =  \frac {R_2}{R_1}V_s-\frac{1}{R_1C}e^\frac{-t}{R_1C}\int(V_s.dt)  $$

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately the laplace transform method is outside of the depth of the class I'm taking - we have only been taught to solve using Kirchoff's laws. Would you be able to help with that method?

Answer (score 0):

I would approach the problem differently. The general equation for an inverting amplifier is \$\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}}=-\frac{R_f}{R_i}\$. Applying that to this circuit: $$\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}}=-\frac{Z_f}{Z_i}=-\frac{Z_{R_{2}}}{Z_{C_1}+Z_{R_1}}=-\frac{R_2}{\frac{1}{j\omega C_1}+R_1}$$ From there, you can simply and work it out in the s domain.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately the laplace transform method is outside of the depth of the class I'm taking - we have only been taught to solve using Kirchoff's laws. Would you be able to help with that method?

Comment: @inkblots You can do it that way too, it's just less convenient.

Comment: understood, unfortunately that is how I'm expected to solve it in this class. If you want to offer further assistance, I would appreciate it. If not, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Junction 3 is a virtual earth, so the voltage at this point is zero.

If \$\small i\$ is the current through \$\small C_1\$ and \$\small R_1\$, KVL for the input circuit is: \$\small V_s=iR_1+\frac{1}{C_1} \int{i dt}\$

Determine the relationship between \$\small i\$ and \$\small V_o\$, then combine the two equations into a 1st order ODE, and solve.

Comment: would setting up it as ( Vin - Vc - 0 ) / R1 =  ( 0 - Vout ) / R2 be correct?

Comment: The current through \$\small R_2\$ is the term on the right of your equation.